# Where should I publish my AS3 class?

Tags: actionscript-3

I made a class that encodes an object in a format 20% smaller than json, and it's not binary. Now I would like to put it somewhere, so people can use it. Where should I post it?

Here's an example object, encoded in JSON:

```
{"glossary":{"GlossDiv":{"GlossList":{"GlossEntry":{"GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language","Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986","ID":"SGML","GlossDef":{"GlossSeeAlso":["GML","XML"],"para":"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook."},"Acronym":"SGML","SortAs":"SGML","GlossSee":"markup"}},"title":"S"},"title":"example glossary"}}
```

And here it is in my format:

```
glossary{GlossDiv{GlossList{GlossEntry{GlossDef{GlossSeeAlso[GML XML]para"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook."}GlossTerm"Standard Generalized Markup Language"GlossSee markup ID SGML Acronym SGML Abbrev"ISO 8879:1986"SortAs SGML}}title S}title"example glossary"}
```

In JSON, the string length is 360, and in my format it is 299

(As you see, my format only puts quotes around the identifier if it contains whitespaces or special characters, it can encode anything that JSON can)

Here's an example readable string:

JSON:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My format:

```
"glossary" {
    "title"     "example glossary"
    "GlossDiv" {
        "title"     "S"
        "GlossList" {
            "GlossEntry" {
                "ID"        "SGML"
                "SortAs"    "SGML"
                "GlossTerm" "Standard Generalized Markup Language"
                "Acronym"   "SGML"
                "Abbrev"    "ISO 8879:1986"
                "GlossDef" {
                    "para"  "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook."
                    "GlossSeeAlso" [
                        "GML"
                        "XML"
                    ]
                }
                "GlossSee" "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Quotes are optional on most strings)

Comment: JSON is popular not only because it provides comparably compact way of packaging objects (then for example XML), but also because it is compatible for example with JavaScript and is supported across vast variety of developing tools and platforms. Something to have in mind.

Comment: Also, is your format so much more compact then JSON? What would 60 or 100 additional characters add to traffic, when already hundreds of kilobytes do not really count.

Comment: Well, when you are working with a multiplayer game, the packets are much bigger than that, and every byte counts. If you write it to a binary socket and then deflate it, it's even smaller, 80 bytes.

Comment: By the way, I made some tests, my class is about 2~4 times faster than json to encode objects and 20% ~ 50% faster to decode objects.

Comment: For anyone interested, it's hosted on http://code.google.com/p/m28keyvalue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are wanting to release this as an open source project, one of the following.

google code : http://code.google.com/
github : https://github.com/

If enough people like it and start using it, you could ask to have it added to as3corelib https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

Comment: My library is under MIT License, as3corelib uses BSD License, do I need to change to have any change to have it included in the lib?